# How to return just a single field of a collection using JPQL?

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

In my database I have software packages and those software packages have maintainers. Now I'd like to return just the maintainers' names for a given software package. `Package` and `Maintainer` have a `ManyToMany` association.

I've tried several things but didn't really succeed.

This returns the whole Maintainer entity that I currently use.

```
select p.maintainers from Package p where p.name = :name
```

However in the end I'm only interested in the names and I think there must be a way to directly return a `Set<String>` from the query. Currently I'm doing this in code.

```java
var maintainers = repo.findMaintainersByPackageName(name);
return maintainers.stream().map(m -> m.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
select p.maintainers.name from Package p where p.name = :name
```

That results in an error

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

I also tried coming from the other side.

```
select m.name from Maintainer m where m.packages.name = :name
```

Unfortunately I also get an error

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection

So basically the question is, how do I return a single field of a collection in jpql? I'm a bit lost.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you question is not clear  ..  you are seacrhing trhe same name you have in where condition??  .. update yoru question and add the involved  tables  schema .. and also a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use INNER JOIN in your JPQL.
something like

```
"select m.name from Maintainer m INNER JOIN m.packages p where p.name = :name"
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course :) I was mentally afk.